# Android 6 Home screen sweep right (stock)

Tags: screen, home-screen-shortcuts, home-screen

(in stock Android, no any UI gadgets installed)

At home screen I can sweep to right direction
(screens right of home screen) and more screens appear to put my icons...

In old versions of Android I could also sweep to left direction
to put icons... but now appears a google search screen...

How can I configure Android get the old behavior...
same as saying... sweep to left and appears a empty screen to put my icons...

Thx

Answer (score 0):

That's how Google Launcher is intended to work, so if you wish to swipe left/right to have available screens for widgets and icons, you'll want a third-party launcher to do that.

Comment: "(...)in old versions of Android I could also sweep to left direction
to put icons... but now appears a google search screen(...)" ...

Comment: don't want to use 3rd party launcher... just want to solve problem with default launcher.... thx

Comment: If you are swiping left to right and getting Google Search with various cards,  that is how Google Launcher is intended to work, and they updated it to do this a while ago.  There is no setting within the Google app to change this behavior.

Comment: If has no way to re-config back old behaviour (which I think was more productive) I think that is a strategic error from Goolgle... too bad... Thx anyway for the info dude !